# Just installed QtOpenGL but cannot import it (from Python)

Tags: python, opengl, pyqt, apt-get, pyopengl

I just installed it with apt-get on debian linux with

```
apt-get install libqt4-opengl
```

the rest of PyQt4 is available, but I cant get to this new module.

```
from PyQt4 import QtOpenGL
```

raises ImportError. any idea what to do?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Did you forget to install the Python bindings?

```
apt-get install python-qt4-gl
```

Answer (score 13):

For Python3, I had to do `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt4.qtopengl`